# Is it forbidden to publish misleading advertising?

Tags: halacha, sheker-false, publications

May a Jew publish, in print, online, or elsewhere, advertising which they have reason to suspect is not accurate? Not to get bogged down in an example; but let's say the publisher of a Jewish newspaper has reason to believe that an ad promising that God will answer your prayers if you send money to a certain organization may not be completely accurate. Does the publisher sin, possibly transgressing lifnei eiver, m'dvar sheker tirchak, or perhaps other issurim, by publishing the ad?

Comment: Journal of Halacha and Contemporary Society had a piece long ago about advertising, including something like weasel words, "cleans like a white tornado" [sound cool, but means nothing] -- which is a bit different than actually promising something false.

Comment: You hit upon one of my pet peeves!

Comment: I heard that Rabbi Levenoni of Torah Vodaath tried to justify it by using an אנן סהדי (halachic Judicial Notice) that everyone understands advertisements are exaggerated/misleading. Unfortunately I don't see how it answers your question because אנן סהדי that there are people who *do* believe the prayer ads.

Answer (score 1):

[Jewish Law's article on Placing a Stumbling Block Before the Blind Person:](http://www.jlaw.com/Articles/placingstumbling.html) defines  lifnei iver:

> The principle of lifnei iver prohibits one from giving bad advice to
>   another person. Thus, one should not advise another party that it is
>   in his interest to sell his field in order to buy a donkey, when his
>   true intention is to buy the field for himself. By concealing the
>   ulterior motive of his advice, he has violated the principle of lifnei
>   iver (Midrash Sifra, Leviticus 19:14). In fact, the Midrash explains
>   the reason the verse ends with the warning about fearing God: Human
>   beings do not know whether advice proffered to them by friends is good
>   or bad. Often, advice is given with an ulterior motive. Only God knows
>   the true motive of the advice giver.

He asserts (without a source) that

> Running advertisements that are intended to mislead the public are
>   violations of lifnei iver since this is tantamount to providing people
>   with bad advice.

The wording “running advertisements” certainly applies to the advertiser. It might apply to the publisher – see later.

[“HALACHA FOR TODAY”](http://halachafortodaycom.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/archives-hilchos-midvar-sheker-tirchak.html) has an article on “HILCHOS MIDVAR SHEKER TIRCHAK”.

He writes:

> 1) An extension of the prohibition to lie is the prohibition to cheat
>   and be dishonest in business. It is prohibited to fool, mislead or
>   deceive customers, clients or any other people in the process of
>   conducting business or any other interpersonal matters. This is
>   referred to in Halacha as “Geneivas Da’as “(literally: stealing
>   knowledge) The prohibition of Geneivas Da’as applies to men and women
>   and to Jews and non Jews alike. (See Talmud Chulin 94a-b, Shulchan
>   Aruch Choshen Mishpat Siman 228) 2) If one is selling merchandise that
>   has a defect, they must notify the prospective buyer of this
>   defect. (See Pele Yoetz, Topic: Sheker, Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim
>   Siman 156:1 and Aruch HaShulchan 156:3)

Again this certainly applies to the advertiser.

Regarding the publisher, Dr. Meir Tamari, director of the Center for Business Ethics at the Jerusalem College of Technology in an [article on lifnei iver,](http://www.myjewishlearning.com/practices/Ethics/Business_Ethics/In_Practice/Ethical_Practices_at_Work/Assisting_a_Perpetrator.shtml?p=3) writes (in relation to arms sales but I believe the principle can be used in this question too)

> One violation of the biblical injunction not to "place a stumbling
>   block in the path of the blind" is **aiding and abetting an illegal or
>   unethical transaction**.

Thus an advertiser who makes promises that may not be completely accurate transgresses and the publisher who aids the advertiser also sins.

Answer (score 1):

R' Moshe has a teshuva (Igros Moshe CM 2:30) about cheating on the NY Regents, in which he says that g'neivas da'as that leads to actual monetary results is g'zeila.  Specifically, he writes that since a later prospective employer who wants someone educated will hire him because he passed the Regents, and his passing of the Regents gives off the false impression that he is educated, then it is forbidden as an act of theft.

If this ad is giving a false impression which causes people to spend money, then it would constitute actual theft according to R' Moshe.

Comment: What would be an example of g'neivas da'as without monetary results? I believe the classic example is buying a diamond from someone who thinks it is a worthless rock.

Comment: @Yishai _I_ believe the classic example is pretending that you are serving a nice dish in honor of a guest when you were planning on having that dish anyways.  No monetary result there.