# How far must a publisher go to mitigate possible lashon hara?

Tags: halacha, internet, safek, lashon-hara-slander

This question is about sites that host community-contributed content, like Wikipedia, Reddit, or blogging platforms like LiveJournal communities.  Suppose somebody posts something negative about an individual on such a site, something that might or might not be *lashon hara* (it's not clear).  What does *halacha* say the overseers of the site (Wikipedia admins, etc) need to do in response if they should happen to be Jewish?  Consider several cases:

- The negative content is already widely-known (been in the press, for example).
- The negative content is not already widely-known or is even new.
- The negative content wasn't directly posted to your site but was linked.
- The negative content has been removed from the "main view" (Wikipedia article, blog front page, etc) but is still available via a specific URL.

How far does a Jew who happens to be in an administrative role have to go to prevent the spread of possible *lashon hara* in cases like this?  Is it enough that the information isn't directly on his site, or is there but buried, or does *halacha* call for him to purge it if that capability is available to him?

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2094/how-useful-are-parameters-or-extent-questions

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48350/5323

Comment: @Shokhet thanks for pointing that out.  The related question seems to be a *l'hatchilah* situation; this is more a *b'diaved* and indirect one (the publisher didn't personally put the content there in the first place but has become aware of it).

Comment: Part of the reason why I didn't VTC as duplicate ;-)